# How are entire directory trees "required" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, recursion, directory, require

A lot of the questions and resources on the web have given ways to require a directory of files (e.g. `Dir["/path/to/directory/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }`). What I haven't been able to find however are ways to require whole trees of files, a.k.a directories w/ more directories and files in them. On top of that, a lot of the methods I found (including the one I previously mentioned) online have returned "Cannot load such file" errors. What's the most efficient way to recursively require files throughout file trees that's compatible w/ the latest Ruby version?

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this:

```
Dir["/path/to/directory/**/*.rb"].each{|file| require file }
```

The `**` means "recursive directory search"

Comment: For some reason when that's used I get returns for undeclared resources that aren't being included in any of the available resources... in other words, resources are being returned for my resources' resources. :P Maybe a bunder issue or something?